# navigating back without losing information in single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single page application where one of the pages is a search function that brings up contact info where those results can be edited, deleted, etc.

currently, if I am doing something such as editing a contact info, and I want to go back for whatever reason to the search page, I lose the search and have to enter it in again.

[image]

My question is, is there any way to change the behavior of the browsers back button to retain the information that was in the search field? Or would it be easier to code in some sort of "soft" back button on the page to take me back?

Examples are much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) can remember state.

Comment: A simple angular service is all you really need. Store any state there and when controller fires load whatever model is stored in service(if any). Or as mentioned above use state saving in ui-router. If you want pageload persistence couple it to localStorage

Comment: @charlietfl can you give me an example of such a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultra simplistic service example that will bind the search input directly to property in service.

If need localStorage support for page load persistence should bind method to ng-change or use ngStorage module to bind directly to localStorage

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .service('searchService', searchService)
  .controller('searchCtrl', searchCtrl)

function searchService($http /* and any other injections needed*/ ) {
  this.state = {
    searchTerm = ''// pull value from localStorage if desired and modify to use setter bound to change event to update localStorage
  }; 

  // add any methods for $http if needed
  this.updateServer = function(value) {
    return $http.post(....
    }
  }
}

function searchCtrl($scope, searchService) {
  // since is object updating any properrties in view will be inherited in service
  $scope.state = searchService.state
}
```

View

```
<input ng-model="state.searchTerm">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use redux coupled with redux-persist so that your application state will persist after navigation using local storage in the browser.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/docs

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Angular bindings for redux:
https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux